# New document not being created in Sanity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, sanity

Hi I am a starter to sanity, and I was planning to use it as my CMS. I created a form that the client could enter the details. The enter data then could be sent over and saved in Sanity

#### A brief on my project

I am using **Typescript**, **Next.js** and **Tailwind CSS** in my project. It is an e-commerce site for selling containers.

The problem I am facing is that a new document is not being created even though:

1. I set up my Santy Client. (Sanity Schema is given below ):

```js
export default {
  name: "container",
  title: "Container",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    {
      name: "container_name",
      title: "Container Name",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "container_origin",
      title: "Container Origin",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "container_type",
      title: "Container Type",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "container_size",
      title: "Container Size",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "container_status",
      title: "Container Status",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "container_description",
      title: "Container Description",
      type: "text",
    },
    {
      name: "container_target_price",
      title: "Container Target Price",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      name: "container_total_price",
      title: "Container Total Price",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
};
```

Sanity Client Code:

```
import { createClient } from 'next-sanity'

export const config = {
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET || 'production',
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  apiVersion: '2022-05-07',
  useCdn: false,
}

export const sanityClient = createClient(config)
```

2. I made sure my Project ID, Sanity Token was correct
3. Even used the `create()` method as mentioned in the Docs.
4. Tried adding a new CORS origins `http://localhost:3000`

To start off this is the Form page. The user has to put in the details:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ContainerInfo } from "../typings";

const addContainer = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState<string>("");
  console.log(input);

  const addTheContainer = async () => {
    const containerInfo: ContainerInfo = {
      container_name: input,
      container_origin: "",
      container_type: "",
      container_size: "",
      container_status: "",
      container_description: "",
      container_target_Price: "",
      container_total_Price: "",
    };
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTheContainer();
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-dark-bluey h-screen  flex flex-col px-10 overflow-y-scroll scrollbar-hide justify-center">
      <form className="space-y-3 ">
        <h1 className="text-orangey text-4xl font-bold text-center mb-2">
          Add a Container
        </h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="w-full rounded-full placeholder:font-semibold placeholder:text-slate-400 text-slate-300 bg-slate-900 px-4 py-2 outline-none font-semibold"
          placeholder="Container Name"
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-orangey px-4 py-2 w-full rounded-full font-medium"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          Add Container
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default addContainer;
```

Then I created a file called `typings.d.ts` file with the code below:

```js
export interface Container extends ContainerInfo {
  _id: string;
  _createdAt: string;
  _updatedAt: string;
  _rev: string;
  _type: "container";
}

export type ContainerInfo = {
  container_name: string;
  container_origin: string;
  container_type: string;
  container_size: string;
  container_status: string;
  container_description: string;
  container_target_Price: string;
  container_total_Price: string;
};
```

I created a `addContainer.ts` file in the `project_name\pages\api` directory. And added the following code:

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { ContainerInfo } from '../../typings'

type Data = {
  message: string
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const data: ContainerInfo = JSON.parse(req.body)

  const mutations = {
    mutations: [
      {
        create: {
          _type: 'container',
          container_name: data.container_name,
          container_origin: data.container_origin,
          container_type: data.container_type,
          container_size: data.container_size,
          container_status: data.container_status,
          container_description: data.container_description,
          container_target_Price: data.container_target_Price,
          container_total_Price: data.container_total_Price,
        },
      },
    ],
  }

  const apiEndPoint = `https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}.api.sanity.io/v2021-06-07/data/mutate/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET}`

  const result = await fetch(apiEndPoint, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SANITY_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(mutations),
    method: 'POST',
  })

    const json = await result.json()

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Added' })
}
```

Can you please help me to figure out. I tried to add the data in this process rather then directly using the `create()` method. Since, I heard that it was more secure this way. Please be informed that I only used 1 input and sent its data to test whether it was saving successfully.I will be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Your `addContainer` component needs to make a request to your endpoint `/api/addContainer` to trigger it.

Comment: "I tried to add the data in this process rather then directly using the `create()` method. Since, I heard that it was more secure this way." I don't believe this to be the case; plus, the `create()` method does exactly what you need and abstracts away the Mutation API, so you remove a bunch of complexity.

Comment: Thanks @Geoff . The `create()` method does make matters more simple and saved a lot of time.